# String index out of range: -5

Tags: java

I have a problem when i test runQuery, the problem is String index out of range: -5 and i can't find the solution

```
@Test 
void testRunQuery() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    final Answer answer = new Answer();
    String[] args = new String[5];

    final String year = "yyyy ";
    final String month = "mm ";
    final String day = "dd ";
    final String limit = "limit ";
    args[0] = year.substring(5);
    args[1] = month.substring(3);
    args[2] = day.substring(3);
    args[3] = null;
    args[4] = limit.substring(6);

    Job result = answer.runQuery(args);
    assertNotNull(result);

}
```

And this is runQuery where i make the query

```
public  Job runQuery(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
    // See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/
    // Variabili per le query
    final Integer yyyy=Integer.valueOf(args[ZERO].substring(FIVE)),
            mm=Integer.valueOf(args[ONE].substring(THREE)),
            dd=Integer.valueOf(args[TWO].substring(THREE)),
            limit=Integer.valueOf(args[FOUR].substring(SIX));

final QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
    "SELECT DISTINCT owner_user_id "
    + "FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` " 
    + "WHERE extract(year from creation_date) = @yyyy " 
    + "AND extract(month from creation_date) = @mm "
    + "AND extract(day from creation_date) = @dd "
    + "AND owner_user_id is not null "
    + "AND owner_user_id > 0 "
    + "ORDER BY owner_user_id ASC LIMIT @limit ")
    .addNamedParameter("yyyy", QueryParameterValue.int64(yyyy))
    .addNamedParameter("mm", QueryParameterValue.int64(mm))
    .addNamedParameter("dd", QueryParameterValue.int64(dd))
    .addNamedParameter("limit", QueryParameterValue.int64(limit))
    .setUseLegacySql(false).build();

        // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
final JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
Job queryJob=bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

// Wait for the query to complete.
queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

        // Check for errors
        if (queryJob == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
        } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
            // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
            // errors, not just the latest one.
            throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
        }
        return queryJob;
    }
```

```
String index out of range: -5 at the line 93 of runQuery; this is the line:
final Integer yyyy=Integer.valueOf(args[ZERO].substring(FIVE))
```

Comment: Show your defined constants. Especially the constant `FIVE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood what argument Java's `String.substring` function takes.

In short, you appear to think the argument takes the length of the substring.  It doesn't - rather, it specifies the "begin-index" - ie. where in the supplied string to start copying.

So when you say :

```
final String year = "yyyy ";
args[0] = year.substring(5);
```

you are NOT actually setting args[0] to a 5-character string.  In stead, you are setting it to the part of string "yyyy " starting at position 5 - in other words, you are setting it to empty-string.

So when you subsequently say

```
final Integer yyyy=Integer.valueOf(args[ZERO].substring(FIVE)),
```

and assuming you have ZERO set to 0 and FIVE to 5, this will fail since you have args[0] as empty-string "", and you can't get a substring starting at position 5 from "".

To sum up, if you have

```
    String myString = "smiles";

    System.out.println("substring(0, 4) = <" + myString.substring(0, 4) + ">");
    System.out.println("substring(2, 4) = <" + myString.substring(2, 4) + ">");
    System.out.println("substring(4)    = <" + myString.substring(4) + ">");
```

the output will be :

```
substring(0, 4) = <smil>
substring(2, 4) = <il>
substring(4)    = <es>
```

**In short, get rid of your ".substring" calls in both your test and your main code.**

Check out the spec at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: alright, i find the problem... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You first define a variable

```
 final String year = "yyyy ";
```

then you use subString

```
args[0] = year.substring(5);
```

args[0] is now a String value of nothing( args[0] equals "")

then you are trying to subString it again.

```
final Integer yyyy=Integer.valueOf(args[ZERO].substring(FIVE)),
```

this won't work because args[0] is an empty String.

You should only use substring once, either inside the function or before calling the function.